# Code not looping correctly

Tags: python, loops

This code should print all the coding sequences in a bigger sequence called sequentie.
However it is printing the first found sequence infinitely.

```
def getCodons(sequentie):
    DNA = sequentie
    while 'atg' in DNA:
        start = DNA.find('atg')
        codon = getSequentie(DNA, start)
        DNA = DNA[DNA.index(codon):]


def getSequentie(DNA, start):
    print ('')
    print ("Sequentie:")
    while start+2 < len(DNA):
            codon = DNA[start:start+3]
            if codon == "tag" or codon == "taa" or codon == "tga":
                print (codon, end=' ')
                return codon
                break
            print (codon, end=' ')
            start+=3
```

So output:

> Sequentie:
>   atg aag ttt ttg gta gtt aag ata aag ctc gag act gat att tca tat act gga tga tga
>
> Sequentie:
>   atg aag ttt ttg gta gtt aag ata aag ctc gag act gat att tca tat act gga tga tga
>
> Sequentie:
>   atg aag ttt ttg gta gtt aag ata aag ctc gag act gat att tca tat act gga tga tga
>
> Sequentie:
>   atg aag ttt ttg gta gtt aag ata aag ctc gag act gat att tca tat act gga tga tga
>   ...

for the sequentie
ccagaatggttactatggacatccgccaaccatacaagctatggtgaaatgctttatctatctcatttttagtttcaaagcttttgttataacacatgcaaatccatatccgtaaccaatatccaatcgcttgacatagtctgatgaagtttttggtagttaagataaagctcgagactgatatttcatatactggatgatttagggaaacttgcattctattcatgaacgaatgagtcaatacgagacacaaccaagcatgcaaggagctgtgagttgatgttctatgctatttaagtatttttcgggagatatatatatcttattgttctcctcctcccgagtcaagttgttctaagaaagaaggatctatttcattttgtggattgtctagtttcagggacagacggggtttaggggaagcgctatccgtggctgctatgacatcgaagaaactctgcacgacatggtatgtaatct

I want to get
Sequentie:
atg aag ttt ttg gta gtt aag ata aag ctc gag act gat att tca tat act gga tga tga

and then the next sequence found

Comment: can you please add a sample input and your expected output

Comment: In `getCodons` you probably want `DNA = DNA[DNA.index(codon)+1:]`

Comment: Can you please provide a concrete example input and the expected output? The purpose of the code is hard to get otherwise. BTW, I think you have to write `start+=4` instead of `start+=3`

Comment: This code (2nd function: getSequentie) worked fine in a different script which only needed the first sequence

Comment: in first function you are not setting atg inside the loop, do you?

Comment: You say the first sequence you want to be returned ends with `gga tga tga` but `ggatgatga` is nowhere in the sequence you gave us. Also you must be missing a character in there as the number of characters before the first sequence divided by three is not 0. Clear these things up and you'll have an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you keep finding the same instance of "atg" in your outer loop. This is because *getSequentie* returns a string that always starts with "atg". And so in the next iteration of the loop, *start* will 0 (the *DNA* string starts with "atg"). From that moment onward `DNA.index(codon)` will always yield zero, and so nothing changes in the next iteration, resulting in the infinite loop.

You could solve this by adding 1 here:

```
DNA = DNA[DNA.index(codon)+1:]
```

This way *DNA* will always get shorter, and so the looping will be finite.

You should also define what you want to happen when the ending codon is not found. The second function will return `None` in that case, and the first function should deal with that (it should exit). Probably the sequence should not even have been printed in that case.

It is better to delay the printing until you have the final results. The second function could return the index where the sequence ends (or `None` if the ending codon was not found). Then you could fill a result variable with the sequences and leave the printing to the caller.

Here is code after applying these and some other changes:

```
def getCodons(sequentie):
    DNA = sequentie
    start = 0
    codons = []
    while 'atg' in DNA:
        start = DNA.find('atg', start)
        end = getSequentie(DNA, start)
        if not end:
            break
        codons.append(' '.join([DNA[i:i+3] for i in range(start, end, 3)]))
        start = end
    return codons


def getSequentie(DNA, start):
    for start in range(start, len(DNA)-2, 3):
        if DNA[start:start+3] in ("tag", "taa", "tga"):
            return start+3

sequences = getCodons('ccagaatggttactatggacatccgccaaccatacaagctatggtgaaatgctttatctatctcatttttagtttcaaagcttttgttataacacatgcaaatccatatccgtaaccaatatccaatcgcttgacatagtctgatgaagtttttggtagttaagataaagctcgagactgatatttcatatactggatgatttagggaaacttgcattctattcatgaacgaatgagtcaatacgagacacaaccaagcatgcaaggagctgtgagttgatgttctatgctatttaagtatttttcgggagatatatatatcttattgttctcctcctcccgagtcaagttgttctaagaaagaaggatctatttcattttgtggattgtctagtttcagggacagacggggtttaggggaagcgctatccgtggctgctatgacatcgaagaaactctgcacgacatggtatgtaatct')

print('\n'.join(sequences))
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Eox1).